# Datapager in Listview not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am working in ecommmerce website. I have used Listview control to populate products. On one page I am showing 36 Products. Now If I want to go to next page using paging then it's not working. Page stays at first page only. I tried 2 solutions.

Paging Code

```
protected void OnPagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack) {
        DataPager pgr = products.FindControl("DataPager1") as DataPager;
        if (pgr != null && products.Items.Count != pgr.TotalRowCount) {
            pgr.SetPageProperties(0, pgr.MaximumRows, false);
        }
    }
}
```

I have many CheckBoxList to filters Listview data as well. So here I kept in mind that If user is on Page 10 & applies some filters & if rows < 36 then it should show result from Page 1. In my below code paging is working properly but when above line scenario I mentioned happens then it shows blank page.

```
protected void OnPagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
{
    (products.FindControl("DataPager1") as DataPager).SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
    this.populateProducts();
}
```

UPDATE PageLoad

```
try {
    query = "SELECT * FROM products where stock_status = @stock_status and status = @status";
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stock_status", "Ready Stock");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "active");
    con.Open();
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    ViewState("Data") = dt;
    products.DataSource = dt;
    products.DataBind();
    catHeading.Text = "Products In Ready Stock";
    itemCount.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString;
    catSliderHeader.Text = "Categories";
    Page.Title = "Ready Stock Products" + " | BrandSTIK";
    con.Close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Response.Write(ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven't handled IsPostBack property in Page_Load event and the list view is getting refreshed at every postback. Try below code.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            try {
    query = "SELECT * FROM products where stock_status = @stock_status and status = @status";
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stock_status", "Ready Stock");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "active");
    con.Open();
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    ViewState("Data") = dt;
    products.DataSource = dt;
    products.DataBind();
    catHeading.Text = "Products In Ready Stock";
    itemCount.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString;
    catSliderHeader.Text = "Categories";
    Page.Title = "Ready Stock Products" + " | BrandSTIK";
    con.Close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Response.Write(ex);
}
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I put PopulateProducts under isPostback then it is not getting data when page load

Comment: Thanks. You are loading listview at every postback. Load your list view at the first time of page load. Try ! IsPostBack.

Comment: IsPostback in paging?

Comment: this is what i already tried before. If I keep it in postback then it won't load products when user comes first time. If postback occured then only they will see products

Comment: Have you used with "!"?

Comment: Ohh. Sorry Let me try

Comment: No issue. I should have been more specific. Let me know if it works.